# Mouse disappears when plugging in a HDMI monitor and enabling mirroring

Tags: cursor

Only with HDMI monitor and enabled mirroring my mouse simply disappears. I have Mac OS X 10.10.5. I have to remove the HDMI cable or disable mirroring and then it appears again. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It has apparently something to do with Accessibility.

Workaround: try changing the size of the pointer in System Preferences > Accessibility > Display:

- if you had set a bigger pointer, reset it all the way to normal,
- if you had it to normal, set it around ⅔ of the distance between normal and the first tick.

Comment: I have found out that as well, and while this is true that it gives you back the cursor, enabling that without seeing a mouse is a bit tricky. :-) So this is a workaround, not really a solution.

Comment: Are you using a vertical monitor? If so, setting it back to horizontal worked for me.

Comment: No, for me it was a projector. I use miniport otherwise, but when presenting I had this problem. Not good.